# How can I Disable sharepoint notification Email

Tags: exchange-server, smtp, sharepoint-email, notifications

I need to find a way to disable notification emails for certain Setting changes, e.g. like adding people to Groups or Sites.

If this is not possible, I wish to know if it's possible to set email address exceptions, e.g. a list of addresses that SP will not send notifications to.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: When you add people to a Sp group or Site, Sharepoint provides to send an email notification to that User, to notify it's been added to the Portal. I'd like to know if there's some way block these sending to specifics email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As your question isn't very clear, this is just a guess. If this is concering adding persons to groups in SP. You can go to - site settings - site permissions.

If you want to add a person there you can click advanced and disable to sent them an e-mail.

Screenie:[image: Permissionsmail]

Comment: Ok. My question is a security issue. as you has exposed above, think if I'd wish  to block possibility to send to group "all-company-groups". this could be possible by Exchange settings but,  I'd like to find a "Sharepoint Side"  solution for this issue .

Comment: I looked around a bit and the best way to complete this seems to be trough the SMTP. I don't know if its possible by using SP only.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125179(v=exchg.141).aspx#ShellProcedure This link seems to provide the powershells command to disable e-mailadresses at exchange level.